# Restore Launchpad DB from Backup using Bash/Terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, backup, launchpad

Context: I'm using [an OSX shell script](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx) to update my settings system-wide after a fresh OS install. One snag I've ran into is restoring Launchpad.

I have my launchpad DB backed up via GoogleDrive at: `$HOME/GoogleDrive/System/launchpad.db` ... It makes sense to use a `cat` command to replace the Apple database, found with: `find "${HOME}/Library/Application Support/Dock" -name "*-*.db" -maxdepth 1` ... Result: /Users/joshuaberk/Library/Application Support/Dock/441BC58D-D647-45B6-A963-A9DAB110BB47.db

There might be a better way to do this with `ln -s` or `cp` -- ultimately, I'd like it to stay in sync if I make any changes without manually copying, and without having to know the name of the Apple Launchpad DB file ahead of time. It should be a simple `for` loop like this, I'd think:

```
for DB in ~/Library/Application Support/Dock/*-*.db; do
    cat $HOME/GoogleDrive/System/launchpad.db > ${DB}
done
```